# Special Object filtering

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I got an js-object with multiple child object that all are build the same way. They contain a "`valid`" and a "`unique`" property.

I want to get a `newObject` that just includes `.valid == true` objects **and** does just contain a single object for every `unique`-property.

```
let object = {                                   let object = { 
  test1: {                                         test1: {
    valid: true,                                     valid: true,
    unique: "123"                                    unique: "123"
  },                                               },    
  test2: {                                         test5: { 
    valid: true,       -->                           valid: true,  
    unique: "123"                                    unique: "321" 
  },                                               }
  test3: {                                       }  
    valid: false,
    unique: "431"
  }, 
  test5: { 
    valid: true, 
    unique: "321"    
  }   
}
```

This is what I've got so far but I do not know how to go on removing the duplicates.

```js
let object = {
  test1: {
    valid: true,
    unique: "123"
  },
  test2: {
    valid: true,
    unique: "123"
  },
  test3: {
    valid: false,
    unique: "431"
  },
  test5: {
    valid: true,
    unique: "321"
  }
}

Object.filter = (obj, predicate) => Object.keys(obj).filter(key => predicate(obj[key])).reduce((res, key) => (res[key] = obj[key], res), {});

let newObject = Object.filter(object, function(item) { return item.valid }) 
console.log(newObject)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `Set` to hold unique values and then just `reduce` over the `Object.entries` array adding the values that haven't been seen and are `valid` to the object:

```js
let obj = {test1: {valid: true,unique: "123"},test2: {valid: true,unique: "123"},test3: {valid: false,unique: "431"},test5: { valid: true, unique: "321"}   }     
  
let seen = new Set
let filtered = Object.entries(obj).reduce((obj,[key, value]) => {
    if (!seen.has(value.unique) && value.valid){
        seen.add(value.unique)
        obj[key] = value
    }
    return obj
}, {})

console.log(filtered)
```